# Export libraries from python 2 from python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapnik

I am working with python 3. My problem is that each time I install a package, it installs it for python2.

For example, I want to use mapnik, so I've just installed it with homebrew, and then it created a folder for python2.7 in mapnik lib.
So it works when I use Python2.7 but not with python3, cause it cannot find the module mapnik.

How can I add it to python 3 ?
python3 path : /Users/gabrielgautron/documents/python3

At the end of mapnik's installation I have the following :

```
For non-homebrew Python, you need to amend your PYTHONPATH like so:
  export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

So I launch this command in terminal, and then :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Gabriel-Gautron:local gabrielgautron$ python3
Python 3.2.4 (v3.2.4:1e10bdeabe3d, Apr  6 2013, 11:25:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mapnik
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapnik/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from _mapnik import *
ImportError: No module named _mapnik
```

A idea ?

Please :)

Comment: Are you installing it with `pip`? Pip has different flavors for the particular version of python it installs to, like `pip-2.7`, `pip-2.6`, etc. What's the output of `pip --version` or the like?

Comment: I think you're right:
pip 1.3.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)but I am intsalling it with homebrew

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [brew recipe](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/mapnik.rb), it depends on the version of python that's accessible when you run `brew`:

```
def which_python
  "python" + `python -c 'import sys;print(sys.version[:3])'`.strip
end
```

So given that, you should change your `PATH` when invoking `brew` so that you're using `python3` as `python`. For example:

```
# Figure out the path to python3
PY3DIR=`dirname $(which python3)`
# And /then/ install with brew. That will have it use python3 to get its path
PATH=$PY3DIR:$PATH brew install mapnik
```

Comment: When you do the second install, where does it end up getting installed? It'd be nice to verify that the brew recipe is using the correct python version.

Comment: thanks,

It doesn't work for me, and probable made a mistake :

PY3DIR=`/Users/gabrielgautron/py3env/lib/python3.2/site-packages $(which python3)`

then : 

PATH=$PY3DIR:$PATH brew install mapnik

And it still behaves the same way. 
Particularly, i get : 
For non-homebrew Python, you need to amend your PYTHONPATH like so:
  export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: Sorry, i deleted my message. Finally it ended, it was just that the code was so long to compile ..

Comment: I am sorry my problem is unclear. In a few minutes I make a clearer explanation..

Comment: So, here is more clearly my problem:
@dan.lecocq
I've maid the installation of mapnik with your commands Dan, and he doesn't had any file to my python3.2 site-packages folder.

It works, I get the following message : 
    ==> Caveats
    For non-homebrew Python, you need to amend your PYTHONPATH likeso:
    export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

So then i run the command.

But in Python3, the module mapnik is not found.

So i make : 
    sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

Then i have the same ImportError as in my first post...

An idea ?

Comment: Well, one option is that you can try the `--prefix` option in brew to try to point it to your python3 `site-packages` folder, though `brew` warns against the use of `--prefix`. At this point, I'd just do something like `cp -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapnik* /path/to/python3/site-packages/' and see if that works. Again, I _really_ recommend that you don't manipulate `sys.path` in your scripts -- that's something that should either be solved at install time or at worst with environment variables.